# Reverse Proxy and Akamai

Tags: reverse-proxy, akamai

I'm trying to understand how a reverse proxy may impact our website and its performance.  We are looking to create a reverse proxy with servers in two locations:

The main server that hosts our website is in Atlanta.

A subsection of the main website is hosted in Washington state on a subdomain.

We'd like all requests to the subdomain to be redirected to a subfolder on the main website via a reverse proxy.

Can this be done without performance issues considering the two servers are so far apart?

If anyone has experience with Akamai can it be used to accomplish a reverse proxy setup like this?
If so roughly how hard is it to set up for a well-trained Akamai engineer (easy, medium, hard)?

Comment: Very vague questions! Everything depends. I'd setup a reverse proxy in my own network and let akamai replicate from that "origin" server.

Comment: @Daniel I understand setup is critical.  If you assume best case scenario for the reverse proxy setup but had to deal with the servers far apart, do you feel it's possible to get the same performance out of a reverse proxy setup versus just letting the web traffic go directly to the server on the subdomain in Washington?

Comment: It depends on your network, content, DNS, routing, a lot of things. Akamai is fast because they got a lot of servers with short routes to main ISP networks and distribute cachable content/traffic accordingly. If you're serving API/dynamic content, they are not accelerating your traffic, but act as a DDoS protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Akamai, configure your Akamai property to deliver content for your website from your origin in Atlanta (default origin). Then setup a rule for Akamai to source content from your origin in Washington based a specific path (I.e. website subsection).
https://techdocs.akamai.com/property-mgr/docs/path-match

This way Akamai has direct access to each origin and can optimize delivery accordingly. This also helps avoid your reverse proxy from being a single point of failure.

Cheers.